# html5 Moving Wrong object

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Below is code to a HTML5 doc I am trying to get working, I have a ball which should be controlled my the keyboard and a square that should move around the square and change direction once it hits a wall. But I think my move function is moving the hole square not the small pinkish square. Any ideas?

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Canvas Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<section>

<div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="200">
This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas;
var ctx;
var dx = 5;
var dy = 5;
var x = 150;
var y = 100;
var WIDTH = 300;
var HEIGHT = 200;
var x1 = 0,
    y1 = 0;
var dx1 = 4,
    dy1 = 5;

function circle(x, y, r) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.fill();
}


function clear() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

function rect(x, y, w, h) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(x, y, w, h);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
}

function moveball() {    
    x1 += dx1;
    y1 += dy1;
    if (x1 <= 0) dx1 = 4;
    else if (x1 >= 550) dx1 = -4;
    if (y1 <= 0) dy1 = 5;
    else if (y1 >= 550) dy1 = -5;
    ctx.translate(x1, y1);    
}

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    return setInterval(draw, 10);
}

function doKeyDown(evt) {
    switch (evt.keyCode) {
        case 38:
            /* Up arrow was pressed */
            if (y - dy > 0) {
                y -= dy;
            }
            break;
        case 40:
            /* Down arrow was pressed */
            if (y + dy < HEIGHT) {
                y += dy;
            }
            break;
        case 37:
            /* Left arrow was pressed */
            if (x - dx > 0) {
                x -= dx;
            }
            break;
        case 39:
            /* Right arrow was pressed */
            if (x + dx < WIDTH) {
                x += dx;
            }
            break;
    }
}

function draw() {
    clear();
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    rect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    ctx.fillStyle = "purple";
    circle(x, y, 10);

    ctx.fillStyle = "#CC00FF";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
    moveball();    
}

init();
window.addEventListener('keydown', doKeyDown, true);
</script>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8nsQB/2/

Working:

My moveball function should have been called movesquare, I added a function square and called this in the moveball function which I have correctly named movesquare

```
    function square(x1, y1){

ctx.fillStyle="#CC00FF"; 
ctx.fillRect(x1,y1,50,50); 

}
```

Working code:

http://jsfiddle.net/VeEGW/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting close: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andRyanMiller/8nsQB/4/);

There were a number of bugs that were causing odd things to happen. Listed here:

1) You repositioned the entire canvas via the ctx variable on moveball(), which was called repeatedly by setInterval. What you meant to do was simply call the ball, but instead moved the whole canvas.

```
function moveball() {    
    x1 += dx1;
    y1 += dy1;
    if (x1 <= 0) dx1 = 4;
    else if (x1 >= 550) dx1 = -4;
    if (y1 <= 0) dy1 = 5;
    else if (y1 >= 550) dy1 = -5;
    ctx.translate(x1, y1);    
}
```

I updated the code to be the following:

```
function moveball() {
    x1 += dx1;
    y1 += dy1;

    if (x1 <= 0) dx1 = 4;
    else if (x1 >= 300) dx1 = -4;
    if (y1 <= 0) dy1 = 5;
    else if (y1 >= 200) dy1 = -5;  

    ctx.fillStyle = "purple";
    circle(x1, y1, 10);
}
```

2) Your height and width boundaries for the ball's movement were off. I reined them into to 300 x 200, which helped.

3) I still haven't gotten your square to move on keydown, but hey, I think we're making progress. I'll try to tweak a few more things and keep this answer updated.

Comment: Thanks very much really helped :) couldn't see the problem at the time !! peace xx